# Not able to set up config server from GitHub | Error occurred cloning to base directory. cannot open git-upload-pack

Tags: spring-boot, github, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have used many online tutorials and YouTube videos ,But all work fine with Local git Repo.
I have added GitHub URL as follows property file . It works fine in You tube video.

I have used STS .

[Sample GitHub code i followed](https://github.com/krish/microservices-course-on-youtube/tree/master/video_006-git-backed-config-server-and-consumer)

Everything work fine for Local Repo. :-(

>

```
 server:
  port: 8191
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          start
          uri: https://github.com/krish/microservices-course-on-youtube-config-store
          search-paths:
           - 'service-config/*service'
```

When I try to access property file via config server url  I'm facing below error

```
   2020-02-07 12:21:40.867  WARN 123072 --- [nio-8191-exec-1] .c.s.e.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository : Error occured cloning to base directory.

org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/krish/microservices-course-on-youtube-config-store: cannot open git-upload-pack
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:254) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:306) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:200) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.cloneToBasedir(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:574) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.1.0.RC3.jar:2.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.copyRepository(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:549) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.1.0.RC3.jar:2.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.createGitClient(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:532) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.1.0.RC3.jar:2.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.refresh(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:261) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.1.0.RC3.jar:2.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.getLocations(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:240) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.1.0.RC3.jar:2.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.getLocations(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:150) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.1.0.RC3.jar:2.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.findOne(AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.java:47) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.1.0.RC3.jar:2.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.findOne(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:190) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.1.0.RC3.jar:2.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.CompositeEnvironmentRepository.findOne(CompositeEnvironmentRepository.java:46) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.1.0.RC3.jar:2.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentEncryptorEnvironmentRepository.findOne(EnvironmentEncryptorEnvironmentRepository.java:53) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.1.0.RC3.jar:2.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.labelled(EnvironmentController.java:122) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.1.0.RC3.jar:2.1.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.defaultLabel(EnvironmentController.java:106) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.1.0.RC3.jar:2.1.0.RC3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/krish/microservices-course-on-youtube-config-store: cannot open git-upload-pack
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:600) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:362) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:137) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:123) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1271) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:243) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
    ... 77 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:320) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:263) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:258) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:137) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1180) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1091) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:394) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.http.apache.HttpClientConnection.execute(HttpClientConnection.java:254) ~[org.eclipse.jgit.http.apache-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.http.apache.HttpClientConnection.getResponseCode(HttpClientConnection.java:231) ~[org.eclipse.jgit.http.apache-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.HttpSupport.response(HttpSupport.java:207) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:514) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.1.3.201810200350-r.jar:5.1.3.201810200350-r]
    ... 82 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:81) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:351) ~[na:na]
        ... 105 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:448) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:165) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:108) ~[na:na]
    ... 102 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you browse to https://github.com/krish/microservices-course-on-youtube-config-store in a browser? Does the browser have a proxy configured? You might need to configure the same proxy in your JVM.

Comment: Yes I can browse. browser uses default proxy settings. am using a corporate backbone network.Can I change proxy from Command Prompt ?

Comment: Google it: "https proxy JVM" or something.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have in dependencies
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'